# Adding small bitmaps in drawing path

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawing, android-bitmap

In my application I need to add small bitmaps(photos) when I'm drawing in the canvas. Like when I draw there are small photos in the drawing path. How can i achieve this. I searched a lot but I couldn't find answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BitmapShader` in the paint of the path with tile mode repeat.

```
paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, But this is not what i really expecting. this is like paint is set to image. but i need to add many  small whole pngs when I draw in path

Comment: use the above paint to draw your path to get your effect. make sure the size of bitmap is small enough.